# laravel hasManyThrough group by

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationships

So I have the following models : Category, Subcategory, Product, Color.

A category has many subcategories and many products through subcategories. A color can have many products; therefore, a product belongs to color.

From a category I can get the corresponding products by doing:

```
$category = Category::find(1);
$products = $category->products;
 App\Product {#1019
         id: 1,
         subcategory_id: 1,
         color_id: 2,
         created_at: "2016-01-31 13:54:05",
         updated_at: "2016-01-31 13:54:05",
         category_id: 1,
```

Now I will get a bunch of these products. All good until now.

What I want to do is from the $products list, gather all the colors ids on that list resulting in an array. Is there anyway to get it though relationships, something like $colors = $product->allcolors; In other words, group by the available colors.

Obviously right now, doing $product->color is called by the belongsTo('App\Color');

Thanks

Comment: See this answer, it touches on hasManyThrough on many-to-many relationships http://laravel.io/forum/03-04-2014-hasmanythrough-with-many-to-many?page=1#reply-11997

Comment: Thanks will take a look at it!